# why the query is returning every combination

Tags: sql, oracle

My DBMS is oracle.
I have a table **trans** with the following column.

| Trans_id | Emp_no | From_date | To_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-10 | 2021-05-16 |

And an other table **time_result** with the following columns

| Emp_no | Date | W_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 01 |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 02 |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 7.5 |
| 100 | 2021-05-11 | 08 |
| 100 | 2021-05-12 | 01 |
| 100 | 2021-05-12 | 7.5 |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 | 01 |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 | 7.5 |
| 100 | 2021-05-14 | 01 |
| 100 | 2021-05-14 | 7.5 |

And another table **grade** with the following columns

| Emp_no | Date | W_code | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 |  |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-11 | 08 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-12 |  |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 |  | CS |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 |  |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-14 |  |  |

I want this out put

| Emp_no | Date | W_code | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 01 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 02 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-10 | 7.5 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-11 | 08 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-12 | 01 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-12 | 7.5 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 | 01 | CS |
| 100 | 2021-05-13 | 7.5 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-14 | 01 |  |
| 100 | 2021-05-14 | 7.5 |  |

In order to achieve this, I have written this query

`

```
 select  distinct  t.trans_id,
     r.emp_no,
     r.date, 
     r.w_code,
     g.grade 
     from trans t  
     left join time_result r on t.emp_no=r.emp_no
     right join grade g on r.date=g.date
```

`'''

The only problem with this query is, for transaction on 2021-05-13,it’s giving every combination of job grade like this

| Trans_id | Emp_no | Date | W_code | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-10 | 01 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-10 | 02 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-10 | 7.5 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-11 | 08 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-12 | 01 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-12 | 7.5 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-13 | 01 | CS |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-13 | 7.5 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-13 | 01 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-13 | 7.5 | CS |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-14 | 01 |  |
| 102 | 100 | 2021-05-14 | 7.5 |  |

Please advise, in what way the query should be changed to get the desired output.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!!

Comment: Please explain the logic for your results.  It is not obvious.

Comment: Please explain how it is that your query includes the field `trans_id`, but the results you show don't include that field. It would seem to me that the results you're showing are not produced by the query in your question.

Comment: Also,  `Date` is not a valid identifier in Oracle - it must be quoted.

Comment: And just to round it out - there is no table with an alias of `c` in your query.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguities. Actually that was a complicated query so I simplified to ask the question. The logic of the result is that, I need to show the employee's deviation in the job grade. so the grade column when empty shows the employee worked in regular job grade and "CS" shows that the employee worked for some hours for that grade (CS) on that particular date.